# CardImg not loading in Reactstrap

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, reactstrap

I'm trying to just pass in an image to my Card in React to display but it's not working for some reason. Any idea why?

```
render () {
  return (
      <Card as='a' onClick={this.props.fun} style={{ cursor: 'pointer'}}>
        <CardImg top width="100%" src='/hello.jpg' alt="hello img" />
        <CardBody>
          <CardTitle tag="h5">{this.props.title}</CardTitle>
          <CardText>{this.props.text}</CardText>
        </CardBody>
      </Card>
  );
}
```

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Its because you are wrong to write source... try to import your image like this

```
import myImage from "./hello.jpg";

<Card as='a' onClick={this.props.fun} style={{ cursor: 'pointer'}}>
    <CardImg top width="100%" src={myImage} alt="hello img" />
    <CardBody>
      <CardTitle tag="h5">{this.props.title}</CardTitle>
      <CardText>{this.props.text}</CardText>
    </CardBody>
</Card>
```